# Nexus 7 Android File Transfer (Socket Programming in Android)

Tags: android, sockets, send, sendfile

```
public class WiFiLibrary {
public Socket client = null;
public FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
public BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;
public OutputStream outputStream = null;

public void Connect()
{   
    try 
    {      
        client = new Socket("169.254.84.140",9999); 
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void SendFile() 
{
    try
    {
        File file = new File("/sdcard/TEST/TEST.xml");

        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()]; 
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);

        /**reads the file */
        bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); 
        outputStream = client.getOutputStream();

         /** writes file to the output stream byte by byte */
        outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); 
        outputStream.flush();
        bufferedInputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void Disconnect()
{
    try 
    {
        client.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is my client class code for android. But when i said connect it crashes and closes. I add permissions my Manifest (There is no problem on the manifest). I used some part of code s in the past with a different tablet. But I try it Nexus 7 and it just crashed.

Here is my manifest permissions also:

```
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Could anyone an idea what is the problem about my nexus 7 ?? I opened nexus 7 as developer also but nothing was changed. Samely it crashed.

Comment: "crash and close" -> post relevant logcat part and point us to the lines it refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html
The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged. See the document  Designing for Responsiveness.